# Examples on how to export PDF to PowerPoint using Jasper Reports JRPPTxExpoter

Tags: java, pdf-generation, jasper-reports, powerpoint

Does anyone have any experience exporting a PDF to a PPT using the JRPptxExporter in Jasper Reports?

Here is the code that is supposed to do the export:

```
JRPptxExporter exporter = new JRPptxExporter ();
exporter.setParameter(JEExporterParameter.INPUT_FILE, new File("/path/to/my/pdf.pdf"));
exporter.setParameter(JEExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, new File("/path/to/my/ppt.pptx"));
exporter.exportReport();
```

I can verify that the PDF is viewable using Adobe Acrobat.

No matter how I set the "INPUT" of the exporter I get a "StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header" Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a pdf report because that has already passed through an exporter to become a pdf.
For all the jasper reports exporters, the input should be a `JasperPrint` object or its serialised version, a `.jrprint` file.

Comment: Thanks, I did get that one to work... oh well, i was hoping I could get away with something!!!